# Foreach command with a folder with many files using a template txt file

Tags: powershell-2.0

Using the following code to select help select 1 file from a list of many dated files and then copy to share. Using the following code very kindly provided by fellow Stacker

```
$pastdays = -7

$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)

$files = Get-ChildItem "V:\Capacity Manager Size reports\"

$filename = ($files | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Database_Server1_Userdb1_" + $pastdate.Day  + "_" + $pastdate.Month + "_" + $pastdate.Year+ "*.pdf"})

Copy-Item -Path $filename.FullName "\\Server50\report_Archive"
```

I need to expand this process to run for many files in the folder – each with slightly different names but following a common template to the file name

Original filenames examples:

```
Database_Server1_UserDB1_30_10_2012_00_20_51
Database_Server2_UserDB2_30_10_2012_01_20_51
```

Etc

Etc

But im not sure how to best do this in a foreach ?

I was thinking create a template file to load into a variable that holds all the examples of the files to examined before copying

So:

```
$Report_Template = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\FileTemplate_Name.txt";

FileTemplate_name.txt:

Database_Server1_tempdb_

Database_Server1_UserDB1_

Database_Server1_UserDB2_

Database_Server2_UserDB2_

Database_Server2_UserDB4_


$Report_Template = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\QCM_Template_Name.txt";

$pastdays = -7

$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)

$files = Get-ChildItem "V:\Capacity Manager Size reports\"

foreach($template in $Report_Template)

$filename = ($files | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $template + $pastdate.Day  + "_" + $pastdate.Month + "_" + $pastdate.Year+ "*.pdf"})

Copy-Item -Path $filename.FullName "\\Server50\CapacityManagerReports_Archive\"
```

Comment: No one got any ideas about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done the following which seems to work

```
$Report_Template = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\QCM_Template_Name.txt";
$pastdays = -3
$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)
$Results = Get-ChildItem "V:\Capacity Manager Size reports\"
Foreach ($Files in $Results)
{foreach($template in $Report_Template)
 {If ($files.Name -like $($template + $pastdate.Day + "_" + $pastdate.Month + "_" + $pastdate.Year +"*.pdf"))
  {Copy-Item -Path $files.FullName "\\Server50\CapacityManagerReports_Archive\"}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Report_Template = Get-Content "C:\Powershell\QCM_Template_Name.txt";
$pastdays = -7
$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)
$files = Get-ChildItem "V:\Capacity Manager Size reports\"
foreach($template in $Report_Template)
{
    $filename = ($files | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $template + $pastdate.Day  + "_" + $pastdate.Month + "_" + $pastdate.Year+ "*.pdf"})
    Copy-Item -Path $filename.FullName "\\Server50\CapacityManagerReports_Archive\"
}
```

But do you really need template file? Can't you use file extension, or some part of the name, or just copy everything from this date? Maybe your inital folder with files has wrong structure and you should better switch to multiple folders, like separate folder for each Database_Server1?

Comment: Thanks for your respone again - unfortunately the format of the folder and the files is changeable. We could actually use a copy from everything on that date - thats true. However this code you have given gives an error.

Comment: Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:8 char:20
+     Copy-Item -Path <<<<  $filename.FullName "\\server50\CapacityManagerReports_Archive\"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: It means that there's no corresponding file found. Please check that `$template + $pastdate.Day  + "_" + $pastdate.Month + "_" + $pastdate.Year` will show you correct format